# What usage for << redirection in TCSH shell

Tags: csh, tcsh

I understand the `<` input redirection and the two `>` / `>>` output redirections (the double append content in file). But I don't understand `<<` double input redirection.

For example `echo "cat < input | wc > output" | tcsh` produce this output file : `2 2 11` but with `echo "cat << input | wc > output" | tcsh` this produce this output file : `0 0 0`.

What does `<<` do? It seem that it don't send data to wc stdin but why?

Comment: Aside: csh is not advised for new development; it was popular for a time because Bourne was too bare-bones and ksh used to cost money, but neither of those things have been true for decades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In csh, as in POSIX-family shells, `<<` starts a heredoc -- that is, a multi-line string terminated by a line containing only the word immediately after it. Thus, in the following example:

```
cat << input | wc > output
this is test data here
input
```

`this is test data here` is fed as stdin to `cat`, the stdout of which is fed as stdin to `wc`. (By the way, there's no point at all to using `cat` here; you could just `wc <<input >output` with the same effect, and with considerably less inefficiency).